# Stack collection and for loop

Tags: c#, loops, collections, stack

I can't seem to find the issue with my code. Might be that I'm too tired but this is driving me nuts.

The while loop works and iterates through the entire collection and does what it has to do. So does the foreach loop, although I'm uncertain whether creating a copy of the list is even worth considering.

A for loop seems to be the best option for me to go on ahead and change the value of the collection as I iterate through it.

Problem is that it always comes one too short of all the entries in the collection. The meal.count will return 1 at the end of the for loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace HFCSExercise_Lumberjack
{
    class Lumberjack
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        private Stack<Flapjack> meal;

        public Lumberjack(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            meal = new Stack<Flapjack>();
        }

        public int FlapjackCount
        {
            get
            {
                return meal.Count;
            }
        }

        public void TakeFlapjacks(Flapjack food, int howMany)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
            {
                meal.Push(food);
            }
        }

        public void EatFlapjacks()
        {
            //while(meal.Count > 0)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Ed ate a {0} flapjack", meal.Pop().ToString().ToLower());
            //}

            for (int i = 0; i <= meal.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ate a {1} flapjack", Name, meal.Pop().ToString().ToLower());
            }

            //foreach (Flapjack x in meal.ToList())
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("{0} ate a {1} flapjack", Name, meal.Pop().ToString().ToLower());
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Pop` modifies the size of the stack so `meal.Count` decreases while `i` increases. You should store the initial count before the iteration if you want to use a `for` like this. I would use `while(meal.Count > 0) { .. .}` though.

Comment: your for loop won't work as intended because `meal.Count` is not static - it decreases with every `Pop` operation

Comment: This can be been easily debugged by simply stepping through the for loop while observing meal.Count.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, the problem with your logic is that the value of `meal.Count` changes each time you use `meal.Pop()`. Remember that pop is removing an item from the stack.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= meal.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ate a {1} flapjack", Name, meal.Pop().ToString().ToLower());
            }
```

So with the loop above, by the time you get to the middle of the collection (pretend the length was 10 originally) you have popped 5 items, the length is now 5 and you break from the loop without having popped the other half of the stack.

The more intuitive construct here is to use a while;

```
while (meal.Count > 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} ate a {1} flapjack", Name, meal.Pop().ToString().ToLower());
}
Console.WriteLine("Now there are {0} items left!", meal.Count);
```

This will iterate the full stack, popping each item, and printing it. As you can see the print statement I added will prove you've popped every item off the stack.